# "exerts and responds to forces to/from their surrounding"": how to revise?

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

I want to say

"[...] such as how it exerts forces to their surrounding and responds to forces from their surrounding"

However, I do not want to repeat "forces to their surrounding" twice, so but if I connect "exerts" and "responds" together, then I won't be able to change the preposition "to/from" coming after "forces".

So, how can revise this sentence in a compact what so that I won't need to repeat "forces to their surrounding" twice?

Comment: ... such as how it **interacts** with its surroundings.

Comment: @WeatherVane but I want to emphasize the type of that interaction, by explicitly noting that it exerts forces as well as responds to.

Comment: @WeatherVane I support the notion of interaction. Interaction cannot be one way: it implies an action between two things. I would have argued for it in an answer but Weathervane is there first.

Comment: @Anton please feel free to expand that into an answer. I liked 'interaction' because it is birectional without being repetitive. Perhaps you can work in the forcefulness which OP would like.

Comment: Thankyou, I have done what I can. Happy New Year (well, let's hope ...)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is

> It ***exerts forces to*** and ***responds to forces from*** their surrounding

But I am only risking it in fact. A native speaker might be able to tell us if "acrobacies" of such kind are acceptable.

You can certainly try and find synonyms of ***forces*** so as not to stumble on its repetition:

> It ***exerts forces to*** and ***responds to impacts from*** their surrounding

Note: I have respected the precise context you have given but actually the more idiomatic phrase is

> to exert force(s) (singular is more common) ***on*** something

Comment: thanks for the response. *force* in this context a bit technical term so ı can't replace it without affecting the information I want to convey.

Comment: Than keep both.

Answer (score 1):

As commented earlier, an appropriate word is *interaction*.

The key to this is the prefix *inter*:

> inter = a prefix occurring in loanwords from Latin, where it meant “between,” “among,” “in the midst of,” “mutually,” “reciprocally,” “together,” “during” (intercept; interest); on this model, used in the formation of compound words (intercom; interdepartmental).
>
> [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/inter-)

I emphasize the mention of reciprocity, that is of reciprocal *action*. An interaction therefore cannot be one way. It necessarily involves action of one on the other, and *vice versa*.

From this perspective I argue that if "It" (whatever it may be) interacts with its surroundings, each affects the other. "It" exerts a force on the surroundings and they exert a force on "it". In classical physics this is a trivial statement consistent with one of Newton's laws. If the force is more metaphorical than in physics the mutuality is still interactive.

"It interacts with its surroundings." says what needs to be said.

Comment: please see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/556253/exerts-and-responds-to-forces-to-from-their-surrounding-how-to-revise/556277#comment1371388_556255

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what *it* and *their* refer to, but I think you might need to make them  agree—either *it*/*its* or *they*/*their*. As for the compact wording, try:

*[...] such as how it responds to and exerts forces in its surroundings*

*[...] such as how they respond to and exert forces in their surroundings*

To expand it back out:

*[...] such as how it responds to forces in its surroundings and exerts forces in its surroundings*